# Saving multiple values to session array and reading them

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have a problem with saving multiple values (product_id's) to session array without refreshing the page and reading them later on.

This is how I try to save them. My page loads jquery and has session_start(); in the head-section.

```
...             


 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))

{

echo "<a href='#". $row['id'] ."' id='clickme". $row['id'] ."'>Add to list</a> ";

echo "<script>";
echo "$('#clickme". $row['id'] ."').click(function(e) {";
echo "    e.preventDefault(); ";
echo "    $.ajax({";
echo "    type:'POST',";
echo "        url:'list.php', ";
echo "        data: { varname: '". $row['id'] ."'},";
echo "        success:function(response){";
echo "          alert(response);";
echo "        }";
echo "    });";
echo "});";
echo "</script>";

}
```

This is my list.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['list'])) {
  $_SESSION['list'] = array();
}

$_SESSION['list'] = $_POST['varname'];

?>
```

And this is how I try to print the session:

```
<?php
session_start();

 print_r($_SESSION['list']);

?>
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong so any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Not sure what you are doing... but may I suggest you look into local storage.

Comment: I really doubt (without testing) that you can save a session-var via an ajax call, as the php never really hits the browser.

Comment: apart from that: I'd suggest to only have _one_ eventlistener on class `.clickme` (without id) and get the id afterwards (via data-attribute f.e.). same outcome, but cleaner code.

Comment: and finally: here `$_SESSION['list'] = $_POST['varname'];` you would overwrite former entries anyway.